# Getting data from the object, that uses NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nsurlconnection

I have a class, that gets some data using `NSURLConnection`. It's method `getData` creates a request to a server and when some data recieved, method `connection:didRecieveData:` updates some properties.

```c
- (void)getData
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL];
    NSURLConnection *connectionWithRequest = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Processing data
    dataProperty = processedData;
}
```

The problem is, when I create an instance of this class and call method `getData`, I can't immediately get object's properties, because data is not received yet. I've read Apple reference about delegates and protocols, but I don't understand how to implement delegate method for this class, that would work like `connection:didRecieveData:` for `NSURLConnection`.

Can you explain me how to do this? I would be very glad, if you just post a link to an example. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: sorry, NSURLConnection works fine for me. I want to know how to create my own delegate method, that would work like connection:didRecieveData:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand how to implement delegate method for this class, that would work like connection:didRecieveData: for NSURLConnection.

The same way NSURLConnection does:

1. Give this object a property named `delegate`.
2. Set that property to another object.
3. In `connectionDidReceiveData:`, send a message to the delegate.
4. In the delegate, implement the method that the other object will be calling.

Comment: Thank you! It looks simple and I think it's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR API URL"]];

    NSString *email = @"username@gmail.com";
    NSString *password = @"123456";
    NSString *deviceToken = @"simulator";
    NSString *deviceType = @"1";

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&deviceToken=%@&deviceType=%@",email,password,deviceToken,deviceType];

    NSData *requestBodyData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse response, NSData responseData, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
         NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
         NSLog(@"%@",dic[@"data"]);
    }];
```

Comment: Probably some explanation would be helpful since the OP specifically asks for it. Best regards